# Unable to install any R packages "unable to access index for repository"

Tags: r, package, installation

I've tried the major fixes seen on stackoverflow, but no luck:

- Turning off "Use secure download method
- Changing primary CRAN repository to Global
- Uninstalling/reinstalling R

```
    Warning in install.packages :
      unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6:
      cannot open URL "http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES"
```

Any ideas? This all started after trying to install pdftools (which itself was having issues with pkgconfig).

Edit:
Here is the full code block. It manages to download from source, but then gives a zero exit status

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
Installing package into ‘/Users/jackshaw/Library/R/3.6/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'
installing the source package ‘ggplot2’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3031461 bytes (2.9 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.9 MB

[1] "R PROFILE LOADED"

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/c1/5c3yn_tx2fq7nrcjs_kn637r0000gn/T/RtmpjcV10X/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("ggplot2") :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: It looks like you don't have access to the repository for some reason. Have you checked firewall, vpn etc. settings? Have you tried installing  from the terminal (e.g., `RScript -e "install.packages('dplyr', repos
= 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')"`? Or maybe try a few different mirrors: https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html

Comment: @JBGruber Thanks for the help! Yep, checked firewall/vpn. Installing from terminal didn't work, and neither did different mirrors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working from a Mac/OS, you may need to redirect your repo using the following:

`install.packages("dplyr", repo = 'https://mac.R-project.org')`

It appears there was recently a glitch in CRAN: https://community.rstudio.com/t/i-can-t-install-packages-on-r-studio-non-zero-exit-status/52135

Comment: Aha, great! This works for most packages. Sorry for the basic question, but does this only install binary versions? Any tips for getting source versions?